# How to reload a page using javascript after the whole page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I want to reload a page after the whole PHP script is loaded, and printed the result. Yeah, i want an infinite loop

This is the script

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: So which part are you stuck on, waiting for the page to finish loading, or causing the reload?

Comment: I forgot to include the script, added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.location.reload` function to load page. If you need to reload after page completed, use `window.onload` event. (`reload` function has one parameter that can disable cache.)

```
window.onload = function(){ window.location.reload()} //reload with using browser cache
window.onload = function(){ window.location.reload(true)} //reload without using browser cache
```

Another way is sending `refresh` header to browser by set **refresh** header in php:

```
<?php
header("refresh:5"); //loaded page reload after 5 seconds 
?>
```